# Firebird JDBC Monitoring

Tags: jdbc, firebird

I have a web application that is having some database issues and I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to monitor all JDBC activity.

I found this tool http://www.jdbmonitor.com/ and it sounds like it will let me do all that I need, however it states that it does not support `javax.sql.DataSource` which is how our JDBC driver is configured.

The DB I'm using is Firebird 2.5 and the JDBC driver is Jaybird 2.1.6

Does anyone know of a tool I could use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using jamon for monitoring jdbc activities (http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/). As a bonus to sql monitoring you can actually monitor everything else you want:)

Regards,
Rado

Comment: Thanks, This looks like it will do exactly what I need.